# IF ELSE condition with SQL Server trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I am populating a table entirely using triggers, it populates the table if `LocationID` and `ProductID` does not exists and if it already does it updates the given data.

I have posted the following code snippet looking for a possible solution or link to one.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[newpurchase] 
ON [dbo].[PurchaseMaster]
AFTER INSERT 
AS
BEGIN
    IF (((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM StockMaster 
          WHERE LocationID = (SELECT LocationID FROM inserted)) > 0) 
       AND ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM StockMaster 
             WHERE LocationID = (SELECT LocationID FROM inserted)) > 0))

        UPDATE StockMaster 
        SET TotalPurchased = TotalPurchased + (SELECT PurchasedQTY FROM inserted) 
        WHERE LocationID = (SELECT LocationID FROM inserted) 
          AND ProductID = (SELECT ProductID FROM inserted);
    ELSE 
        INSERT INTO StockMaster (LocationID, ProductID, TotalPurchased, TotalSold, OnHand) 
            SELECT LocationID, ProductID, PurchasedQTY, 0, 0 FROM inserted;
    END
```

Comment: What doesn't work about your code?

Comment: Have you considered using a [`merge statement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure exactly what you are looking for. If your return sets cannot be collected dynamically, and you need another table to always update based off the information persisted by another another table then I do think triggers are fine. There is always overhead with triggers, so keep that in mind.

You could do the way you are doing it, and from what I can see on the surface level the trigger may be what you are looking for (but this also depends upon your business needs and relationships of tables). HOWEVER, you will have to be careful if your Insert is a bulk insert then what you have will throw an error.

I also noticed your If statement is checking LocationId twice instead of LocationId and ProductId.

The trigger you are trying to create works with only one value at a time. You could rewrite this to a more set based trigger for when bulk inserts occur. This way if you have one insert or bulk inserts these two queries can perform for that values where needed.

> first you want to update all the values where LocationId and ProductId are the >same found in StockMaster
>   if no values match then nothing will be updated

```
Update StockMaster    
    Set TotalPurchased = sm.TotalPurchased + i.PurchasedQty    
From StockMaster sm     
inner join inserted i on sm.LocationId = i.LocationId and sm.ProductId = i.ProductId
```

> next you want to insert any row that isn't found in StockMaster
>   if all values matched above, they will be weeded out with the wheree condition >and,then nothing would be inserted here, those that didn't match would be 
>   inserted

```
INSERT INTO StockMaster (LocationID, ProductID, TotalPurchased, TotalSold, OnHand)     
    SELECT i.LocationID, i.ProductID, i.PurchasedQTY, 0, 0     
    FROM inserted i    
    left join StockMaster sm on i.LocationId = sm.LocationId and i.ProductId = sm.ProductId    
where sm.{Id} is null;--not {id} is for whatever key this table uses
```